# How can i use twig truncate in Symfony 4

Tags: twig, symfony4

I want to use trancate filter in twig but i have the error:

```
The file "D:\projets\dzairdeals\config/services.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: Indentation problem in "D:\\projets\\dzairdeals\\config/services.yaml" at line 30 (near " twig.extension.text:") in D:\projets\dzairdeals\config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "D:\projets\dzairdeals\config/services.yaml").
```

When I try to add this lines to my `services.yaml`

```
twig.extension.text:
     class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
     tags: - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Have you `composer require twig/extensions` ?

Comment: yes i have install twig/extentions

Comment: According to the error, it seems that it is just a formatting problem in your `yaml` file. 
Check your file indentation.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone coming to this for Symfony 5:

```sh
composer require twig/string-extra
composer require twig/extra-bundle
```

Then you can use the truncate filter like so:

```php
{{ project.title|u.truncate(30, '...') }}
```

Truncate filter is passed a length and an optional string to append to the end if truncated.

`u.` meaning the string on the left is encapsulated in a Unicode object, see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/u.html

Comment: twig/string-extra is the only one needed, however interesting what "u." is...

Comment: @Mecanik  "u." is to encapsulate the string  in a unicode object https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/u.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `twig/extensions` is installed:
`composer require twig/extensions`, if so, you should see a config file auto-generated containing:

```
#config/packages/twig_extensions.yaml

services:
    _defaults:
        public: false
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    # Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension
    #Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: null
```

Comment: twig/extensions is deprecated, use the extra-bundle instead

Answer (score 0):

A correct indentation for your `yaml` file could be :

```
twig.extension.text:
         class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
         tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

or

```
twig.extension.text:
     class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
     tags: [twig.extension]
```